# In my mapping i have two filter transformations and two target tables but target object writing data into first target and second target is empty

Tags: informatica, informatica-powercenter

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CSNTS.jpg)I have one source and two target tables without Primary key. both source and targets are Oracle database. i created a mapping using two filter transformations to load data into two target tables. in both Filter Txn's same condition given i.e., Sal>1500 which satisfies 7 records. When i ran the workflow by keeping target load type 'Bulk' and in run properties it shows 7 records are loaded into each target table but when i check in oracle data base only second table data getting loaded. when i change the Load type to 'Normal' both tables are loaded.
what makes the difference in database ?

Answer (score 0):

For oracle, `bulk` load succeeds when there is no index on the table in database.
So, when you are running in `bulk` mode, load to one target is failing because it has index on it in database.
Mode `Normal` will work with or without index so its working properly.

Comment: In my two target tables no index is defined

Comment: Hmm, do you have any constraints? I can see that both table name ate same? Are they different in database?

Comment: Names are different.. one target nane tgt_emp, another one is tgt_emp1.they are not from the same target instance.

Comment: can you set on `bulk` mode and then run the session in verbose mode. If you can attach that verbose session log to the question, that would be great.